# Displaying custom attribute made add to cart and short descrption hide on product view page

Tags: custom-attributes, magento-2.2.5

I was trying to display a custom attribute to product view page and overwrote the base file with child theme but after that only the custom attribute is showing and rest has disappeared i.e add to cart, QTY and short description . Any idea why?

**app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main product-shop col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.measurements" template="product/view/customattribute.phtml" after="product.info.overview">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getMeasurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="measurements"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

**app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/customattribute.phtml**

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue) { ?>
    <div class="product attibute <?php echo $_className?>">
    <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.measurements" template="product/view/customattribute.phtml" after="product.info.overview">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getMeasurements</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="measurements"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

If you check "product.info.main" name is already assigned for right block in product details page. If you use the same name then it will replace the right container with your new one. So in your case use referenceContainer in place of container.

Comment: Good point but  <move element="product.info.main" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> is added to the base xml file, that I am overriding so now the custom attribute isnt showing

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Sh68V6hW you can view it here

Comment: Above code is not working for you? I am seeing that you are using Infortis theme.

Comment: Custom attribute isn't showing but add to cart and other things are showing and yes, it is infortis theme

Comment: on which section you want to show?

Comment: Just below product name or product description